# Issue with extracting data from a table using rvest library in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm having trouble extracting data from a table on a webpage using the rvest library in R. I'm trying to retrieve the values for the "Enterprise Value per share" variable from the table on the page.

I've tried different approaches, such as identifying the "data-field" attribute or matching text patterns in the rows, but the code doesn't work correctly. The resulting file is empty or there is no data for the variable.

Here's a snippet of the code I've been trying to use:

```
library(rvest)


strona <- "https://www.biznesradar.pl/wskazniki-wartosci-rynkowej/AMICA"


wydobadz_dane <- function(strona1) {

  page <- read_html(strona1)
  

  table <- html_node(page, ".report-table")
  

  rows <- html_nodes(table, "tr")
  

  data <- list()
  

  for (row in rows) {

    message("Sprawdzanie wiersza...")
    

    if ("Enterprise Value na akcję" %in% html_text(row)) {

      message("Znaleziono dane dla zmiennej 'Enterprise Value na akcję'")
      
      values <- html_nodes(row, "td")
      data_row <- sapply(values, function(x) html_text(x))
      data_row <- data_row[-1] 
      data <- c(data, list(data_row)) 
    }
  }
  

  data <- do.call(rbind, data)
  data <- as.data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  return(data)
}


dane <- wydobadz_dane(strona)
```

Could someone please help me resolve this issue? How can I correctly extract data only for the "Enterprise Value na akcję" variable from the table on the webpage?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I have tried using the rvest library in R to extract data from the table. I attempted to identify the relevant rows using attributes or text patterns, but the code did not produce the desired output. I expected to retrieve the values for the 'Enterprise Value per share' variable from the table. However, the resulting file was either empty or did not contain the expected data. I'm seeking assistance in correctly extracting data for the specific variable from the table.

Comment: You do not use `if ("Enterprise Value na akcję" %in% html_text(row))` to match text. Instead, use `if (grepl("Enterprise Value na akcję", html_text(row)))`